# Teestfor a player riding minecart named "car"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I testfor a player riding a Minecart named "car" with scoreboards in version 1.10?

Comment: Found something, doesn't work: `/testfor @a {RootVehicle:[{Entity:{id:"MinecartRideable",CustomName:"car"}}]}`

Comment: I'd just like to point out that you probably don't want to be using `/testfor` to do this.  It's useful in some very specific circumstances, but since you're asking how to do a relatively straight forward test, you're probably going to want to use scoreboard tags instead.

Answer (score 0):

When riding an entity, players will have that entity inside a `RootVehicle` compound tag as such:

[image: Data structure]
[(source)](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format)

This means that you can test players on a named minecart like this:

```
/testfor @a {RootVehicle:{Entity:{id:"MinecartRideable",CustomName:"car"}}}
```

Or, with a scoreboard tag so you can target them later:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a add InCar {RootVehicle:{Entity:{id:"MinecartRideable",CustomName:"car"}}}
```

Comment: Hey, that's what I had and it didn't work, the command I wrote in the comments didn't work either.

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek The command in my answer works as expected from what I've seen. The problem with the command you commented seems to be that you have an unnamed compound tag in a list rather than a named compound tag.